# bash regex matching multiple leading spaces in if-statement

Tags: regex, bash

I'm using bash to read a text file containing full-path filenames one to a line. Some have the starting fwd-slash as the first character but most are indented with three spaces, like so:

```
/my/top/level/file
   /my/top/level/file/one_more.txt
   /my/top/level/file/two_more.txt
```

No problems reading the file, trouble is I can't seem to come up with the correct pattern-matching to grab the filename from these indented lines. I'm using this:

```
if [[ $line =~ ^([[:space:]][[:space:]][[:space:]])(.*)$ ]] ; then
    filename_indented=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
else
    filename=$line
fi
```

I grok that bash pattern-matching isn't as sophisticated as real regex'ing, but I'd like to keep the solution all-bash, w/o using sed.

So what's the trick? I sense subtlties afoot.

Comment: Not sure why you need `[[:space:]]` when a quoted space is enough.

Comment: i think your solution should work. What's wrong with the above?

Comment: What is the output you are getting? If you are using `while read` then the leading spaces will be trucated and the `else` clause will be working fine. That is you need not use any regex match at all. The code you have written is correct and works fine if you assign a variable like `line="   test"`, with the leading spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the file correctly, `read` will automatically trim leading whitespace:

```
$ while read -r line; do echo "fname '$line'"; done < dat/filenames.txt
fname '/my/top/level/file'
fname '/my/top/level/file/one_more.txt'
fname '/my/top/level/file/two_more.txt'
```

Comment: subtlties afoot indeed! I don't work in bash much , was unaware that it magaically eats leading whitespace. Yes, removing all the matching stuff and just using a simple while read works like a charm.  Thanks to all who replied.     But what if my indentations have meaning and I do NOT want read to eat the whitespace so I can base some logic on its existence or not?

Comment: Including IFS='' in my while-clause allows my original code to work corrrectly to differentiate between lines with leading spaces and those without. Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: Setting the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator as `IFS="` will cause your script to hang waiting for a closing quote. Setting `IFS=""` (empty string/null) - no **word splitting** occurs. If left at the default: `<space><tab><newline>` then any sequence of `<space>, <tab>, and <newline>` at the beginning or end are ignored.

Comment: Spend an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong before I stumbled onto this answer.  Didn't know `read` trims... (Is there a flag that controls this?  I don't like it being the default behaviour.)

Comment: @gone - no flag, it's all behavior associated with how IFS is set (or unset). All data handling, input/output, command/process substitution, etc.. all involve word-splitting (how the words are handled/split) While it's a bit strange that it is all associated with IFS, so much of how shell works (and the pitfalls that bite you) lent itself to control by something like an IFS string --- that early solution has stood the test of time. For right, wrong or indifferent, that's what you deal with for word splitting (supplemented by how you quote)